# show popovers on uilabel touch in iphone

Tags: ios4, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a number of UILabels on a single view of a iphone application ios 4.3. How to handle touch events for all these labels at one time? I wanted to show pop overs on touch of that label. I know popovers are not available on iphone and will be making my custom ones.

what i did was using `UITapGestureRecognizer` and adding an action `@selector(labelTap:)` and then doing `[label addGestureRecognizer:TapGestureRecognizerObject`. But when i use the same `UITapGestureRecognizer` for all my UIlabels only the last added label shows the tap action.

i have set userInteractionEnable to YES.

Can any one point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create separate `UITapRecognizer` for tracking different `UILabel`, when a `UIGestureRecognizer` is added to multiple views, it will only track event from last it added to. To better understand why you need different instances of `UITapRecognizer`, think of it as a `UIView` that only handles touches event but doesn't do any drawing.